# Why didn't this code replace the outliers in my columns with the mean?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, outliers

```
   all_data = all_data.where(np.abs(stats.zscore(all_data)) < 1.5, np.nan)
all_data = all_data.fillna(all_data.mean())

#count the outliers in each column (AGAIN)
Q1 = all_data.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = all_data.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
((all_data < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (all_data > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).sum()
```

I tried the code above to remove the outliers in my dataframe. Then I counted the outliers for each column (before and after) and there wasn't much difference. Why isn't the above code removing the outliers? This is the output (left are column names, right is outlier count of column)

```
 f1        0
f2        0
f3     5696
f4     2885
f5        0
f6        0
f7     9969
f8     4405
f9        0
f10    5675
f11       0
f12    5546
f13    4378
f14    2231
f15    3774
f16    2607
f17       0
f18       0
f19    3388
f20       0
f21       0
f22       0
f23    5276
f24       0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: It's in the post right under "#count the outliers in each column (AGAIN)"

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `outliers` with `NaN` then fill the `NaN` with with averages of columns:

```py
df = df.where(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 1.5, np.nan)
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks I tried that but still the outliers aren't being reduced. Any idea why? I updated my post.

Comment: @SofiaRValdez By using `np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3` to judge `outliers`, the `outliers` is `True` or `False`? By using `where()`, I treat the `False` as `outliers`. Also I include `outliers` value when calculate the mean of columns, is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah I used your code to remove outliers/replace with the mean. But if you see the columns I posted above, for some reason there are still several outliers in all my columns

Comment: @SofiaRValdez Do you want to include `outliers` value when calculating the mean of columns?

Comment: No I don't want to include the outliers in the mean

Comment: @SofiaRValdez What confused me is that you use two different ways to judge `outliers` in your post. One is `np.abs(stats.zscore(all_data)) < 1.5`, another is `(all_data < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (all_data > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))`. Is the effect of these two methods the same?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not too sure. Someone had suggested using this code in another post. I re-tried with your updated code and I updated my post. Now there are less outliers but most columns still have a lot. Not sure why this would be

Comment: @SofiaRValdez My intuition is that, after replacing the original outliers, the new data forms a new data distribution. In this distribution, there exist some outliers. But these outliers are not outliers in the original data distribution. You might need a loop to make the all the values are not outliers.

Comment: That's what I thought too but the "outlier count" values for the columns that still have outliers are exactly the same as they were before I replaced the outliers. So, for some reason those specific columns didn't get their outliers replaced

Comment: @SofiaRValdez It is impossible for outliers not to be replaced, you can confirm this by comparing the original dataframe and the replaced dataframe. I think there are two reasons to explain why the number of outliers doesn't change. Firstly, you use two different methods to judge outliers. Secondly, by some coincidence, the replaced dataframe has the same outliers with the original dataframe.